# Crystal report 11.0

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing a report where i am using a parameter PQAO in the record selection i have a formula
 uppercase({PROJ_VIEW.PQAO_NAME}) like uppercase({?PQAO} + "*")

when i put * in the parameter, it brings all the reords where PQAO is not null and is PQAO is null it will not bring back that record. How to i bring back that record. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

add `or isNull(?{PQAO})` to your selection formula